# AccountModel in one screen

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have this app with basic AccountModel that ships with MVC3. The AccountModel have three classes:

- ChangePasswordModel;
- LoginModel;
- RegisterModel;

I want to create an Account/Settings screen so I've create the Settings Action on the Account Controller.

But I can't realize what to do next since this screen will have all account funcionts like change password, change site settings and profile stuff and the ChangePasswordModel is a separate model!

How to post the ChangePassword form inside this /Account/Settings and still get the ChangePassword action working?

How to unify this in one screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap each set of functionality in a new form then you can accomplish what you want... You can use

```
<% using(Html.BeginRouteForm(...) %>
```

to pretty cleanly specify where you would like each section of the page to go... I would recommend that you send each to different actions (even if they are in the same controller) so as to keep your model binding simpler.

This can get ugly if you have var A in one form but want to retrieve it in a different form.

So long as you want to just put everything on the same screen each form can successfully represent their own model cleanly then this is a pretty decent way to do this (IMO)

**EDIT**

If you're used to ASP.net and MVC is a little new to you, putting multiple forms on the same page is against the ASP.net nature, but in mvc (as mentioned) you can do this very effectively.

**EDIT for Links**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginrouteform.aspx

http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/01/31/the-mvc-platform-more-form-extension-methods.aspx

Comment: Interesting. So I just need to have a form with the same names in the model that the one the action recieves and thigs will just work? By the way, can I bind multiple models in this screen to get validation errors back?

Comment: yeah, exactly... You (and I for a long time) are probably just used to the ASP.NET style of one form per page... I'm adding some BeginRouteForm links to my post... Look at the last edit...

Comment: Also note that I kept harping on BeginRouteForm because I typically like to use Route Mapping pretty heavily... Note that Html.BeginForm would effectively have the same desired result!

Comment: No, sir, I'm not like you. I'm just padawan yet. Still learning, master.

Comment: The more I learn, the more I realize how much of a padawan I still am :)